# Arduino and C# Connection using Bluno Nano(DFR0296)

Tags: c#, bluetooth, arduino, arduino-ide

1. The code below is Arduino IDE code,
2. works well on the Arduino-uno and Arduino-pro microboard.
3. This sends value(32-sized buffer) to a 'C# Serial Communication Program' from Arduino.
4. But when I replace Arduino with Bluno Nano(DFR0296) and run it, the value cannot be transferred to the C# program. (Pin number checked correctly)
5. Am I wrong in the Arduino code or should I correct it in the C# code?

**sketch_dec05a.ino**

```
int En0 = 7;  //  Low enabled
int En1 = 6;  //  Low enabled

int S0  = 5;
int S1  = 4;
int S2  = 3; 
int S3  = 2;


int SIG_pin = A7;

typedef union {
  uint16_t values[32];
  uint8_t buffer[70];
} xData;

xData data;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(En0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(En1, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(S0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S3, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {


while(!Serial.available()) ;

Serial.read();

for(int i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i++){
    data.values[i] = readMux(i);
  }

  Serial.write(data.buffer, 64);


}


int readMux(int channel){
  int controlPin[] = {S0,S1,S2,S3,En0,En1};

  int muxChannel[32][6]={
    {0,0,0,0,0,1}, //channel 0
    {0,0,0,1,0,1}, //channel 1
    {0,0,1,0,0,1}, //channel 2
    {0,0,1,1,0,1}, //channel 3
    {0,1,0,0,0,1}, //channel 4
    {0,1,0,1,0,1}, //channel 5
    {0,1,1,0,0,1}, //channel 6
    {0,1,1,1,0,1}, //channel 7
    {1,0,0,0,0,1}, //channel 8
    {1,0,0,1,0,1}, //channel 9
    {1,0,1,0,0,1}, //channel 10
    {1,0,1,1,0,1}, //channel 11
    {1,1,0,0,0,1}, //channel 12
    {1,1,0,1,0,1}, //channel 13
    {1,1,1,0,0,1}, //channel 14
    {1,1,1,1,0,1}, //channel 15
    {0,0,0,0,1,0}, //channel 16
    {0,0,0,1,1,0}, //channel 17
    {0,0,1,0,1,0}, //channel 18
    {0,0,1,1,1,0}, //channel 19
    {0,1,0,0,1,0}, //channel 20
    {0,1,0,1,1,0}, //channel 21
    {0,1,1,0,1,0}, //channel 22
    {0,1,1,1,1,0}, //channel 23
    {1,0,0,0,1,0}, //channel 24
    {1,0,0,1,1,0}, //channel 25
    {1,0,1,0,1,0}, //channel 26
    {1,0,1,1,1,0}, //channel 27
    {1,1,0,0,1,0}, //channel 28
    {1,1,0,1,1,0}, //channel 29
    {1,1,1,0,1,0}, //channel 30
    {1,1,1,1,1,0}  //channel 31
  };

  //loop through the 6 sig
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i ++){
    digitalWrite(controlPin[i], muxChannel[channel][i]);
  }

  //read the value at the SIG pin
  int val = analogRead(SIG_pin);

  //return the value
  return val;
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe how you have it connected, and how you are powering it? 
Do you get any serial data, or is it just giving you bad data?

Comment: Try this code to see if you even get basic serial comms working:
`void setup() 
    {
        Serial.begin(115200);  //initial the Serial
    }
    
    void loop() {
    if (Serial.available())  {
    Serial.write(Serial.read());//send what has been received
    Serial.println();   //print line feed character
  }
}`

Comment: I give up... not sure how to format that better in the comments...

Comment: Better version [link](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Bluno_SKU_DFR0267#Bluno_Basic_Demo)
Also instructions

Comment: @Thoryn Hawley Thanks! but..I couldnt work Blunonano :( I just gave up and threw away that board

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old, but maybe someone else will need the answer.  In programs written in C# on the PC in the serial port initialisation code, add the line:

```
serial.DtrEnable = true;
```